# What is the difference between Fortran's .f and .for files?

Tags: fortran

I am a beginner in Fortran programming; I wonder what the differences between Fortran's fixed format `.f` and `.for` files are.

It will be quite helpful for me if you can explain the fundamental difference between them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fortran in reality does not prescribe any extension for source files written in the language. This is similar to what happens on Linux, where extensions can be absent and do not attach special meaning to the bits of a filename.

Having said that, there are conventions among Fortran programmers:

- `.f`, `.for` or, less likely, `.f77` for *fixed-form* source code (rigid *Fortran77* formatting rules: code begins on 7th column of each line, 6th is for continuation character, by convention `*` or `&`);
- `.f90` (less used: `.f95`, `.f03` and `.f08`) for *free-form* source code (modern Fortran, from F90 on: write anywhere you please, as done in other languages);
- `.F`, `.F90` in upper-case, for source code, either fixed-form or free-form, that contain special instructions, and must go through the C pre-processor.

So there is not really much a difference in using either `.f` or `.for`, they both refer to fortran77 fixed-format, and not even to that when compiling on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no difference at all. For older, fixed-form code, such as FORTRAN 77, the .f or .for extensions are typically used, as you see [here](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/File+extensions).